# Site hacked using DNS x-dns-prefetch-control

Tags: html, dns, tags, web, meta

One of my sites came up as hacked on Google recently so I have been trying to fix the problem. When I looked at it using a browser, everything looked normal, but when I looked at it using "**Fetch as Google**" a load of junk came up after the first meta tag. I got rid of the spurious code by adding:

```html
<http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off">
```

to the header, but my question is: Does anyone have any idea how this could have happened please? I am on an `IIS server` but when speaking to the host company (123-reg) they said that it was not possible for their server to be hacked. Has anyone else had this sort of problem?

I have fixed the issue on the surface but I am concerned with where the vulnerability lies.

Thanks in advance for any help with this matter.